# 407 Proxy Authentication Required when trying to install a package but there's no proxy

Tags: 14.04, networking, apt, proxy, mongodb

Following these instructions http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ of how to install mongodb, I got an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install  mongodb-org
[sudo] password for alex: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjpeg62 python-colorama python-distlib python-html5lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 50.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 157 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-tools
  mongodb-org
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse mongodb-org-shell amd64 3.0.5
  407  Proxy Authentication Required
Err http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse mongodb-org-server amd64 3.0.5
  407  Proxy Authentication Required
Err http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse mongodb-org-mongos amd64 3.0.5
  407  Proxy Authentication Required
Err http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse mongodb-org-tools amd64 3.0.5
  407  Proxy Authentication Required
Err http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse mongodb-org amd64 3.0.5
  407  Proxy Authentication Required
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-shell_3.0.5_amd64.deb  407  Proxy Authentication Required

E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-server_3.0.5_amd64.deb  407  Proxy Authentication Required

E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-mongos_3.0.5_amd64.deb  407  Proxy Authentication Required

E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-tools_3.0.5_amd64.deb  407  Proxy Authentication Required

E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/mongodb-org_3.0.5_amd64.deb  407  Proxy Authentication Required

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

There's no proxy I go to the Internet through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your command line, see if can you do the following:

```
$ echo "GET / HTTP/1.1
> 
> " | nc repo.mongodb.org 80
```

**note** pay attention to the quotes, there are two returns in the string pipped to netcat (may be called nc on your system).  You should get a response like below.  If netcat is not installed, then you can use telnet as well if it happens to be installed.

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: CloudFront Date: Thu, 06 Aug 2015
>   17:39:05 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 551 Connection:
>   close X-Cache: Error from cloudfront Via: 1.1
>   7dcd2c4f2f9e03bee8b952ac4503c140.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>   X-Amz-Cf-Id: A4aLCzPa4Wfqfp5eKZRWTLrU79JdCrd7C0lDPfyj39fynCyZr_SI0A==
>
> ERROR: The request could not be satisfied
>
> ## ERROR
>
> ### The request could not be satisfied.
>
> Bad request.
>
> ```
>  Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID:
>   A4aLCzPa4Wfqfp5eKZRWTLrU79JdCrd7C0lDPfyj39fynCyZr_SI0A==
> ```

If you do not get that, then your HTTP connection is being intercepted by a proxy of some sort, possibly a TCP proxy or transparent proxy - and you would need to talk with your network provider for more information.

Comment: i got that but the initial error persists.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a proxy setup explicitly for apt, in the /etc/apt/*.conf files?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto/#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy ).